# how to calculate JDK Rs Ratio from a brazilian stock using yahoofinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to calculate JDK - RS Ratio using python, however it seems it is not working well.

These are some articles that i've found on the internet, concerning JDK RS Ratio:

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17963/how-to-calculate-the-jdk-rs-ratio

https://marginstone.com/how-to-create-a-relative-rotation-graph-on-excel/

https://github.com/vlaranjo/Vasconomics_Materials/blob/master/Articles/RRG/Relative_Rotation_Graphs.ipynb

This is my python code, using Taurus (TASA4) stock and Ibovespa (benchmark - ^BVSP) as an example:

```
df_tasa = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['^BVSP', 'TASA4.SA'], start_date, end_date)['Adj Close'].pct_change().dropna().reset_index()
df_tasa['price_relative'] = (df_tasa.iloc[:,2] / df_tasa.iloc[:,1]) * 100
df_tasa['price_relative_roll10_mean'] = df_tasa.price_relative.rolling(10).mean()
df_tasa['price_relative_roll10_std'] = df_tasa.price_relative.rolling(10).std() + 1
df_tasa['Jdk_rs_ratio'] = 100 + ((df_tasa.price_relative - df_tasa.price_relative_roll10_mean) / df_tasa.price_relative_roll10_std)
df_tasa['Jdk_rs_ratio'] = df_tasa['Jdk_rs_ratio'].round(2)
df_tasa.dropna(inplace=True)
df_tasa.tail()
```

The above code has returned the following table:
[image]

However, it's seems that my python code has some error because when i compared python daframe with RRG Software, i've saw that Taurus (TASA4) JDK Rs Ratio has ranged between 96 and 98.

[image]

The above beind said, could you please help me correctly calculate JDK RS Ratio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add 1 in this line

df_tasa.price_relative.rolling(10).std() + 1

I think you should standardize as 100 + (value-mean)/SD

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30057684)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.